# Efficient Way to Iterate Through Rows and Apply Conversions

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-loc

I am looking for a more efficient way to perform a check and then apply transformations if necessary.

Here is my current code

```py
for i in tqdm(df.index):
    if df.loc[i,'WHP Total Acres'] > df.loc[i,'GIS_ACRES']:
        conv_factor = (df.loc[i,'GIS_ACRES'])/(df.loc[i,'WHP Total Acres'])
        df.loc[i,'Very Low'] = df.loc[i,'Very Low'] * conv_factor
        df.loc[i,'Low'] = df.loc[i,'Low'] * conv_factor
        df.loc[i,'Moderate'] = df.loc[i,'Moderate'] * conv_factor
        df.loc[i,'High'] = df.loc[i,'High'] * conv_factor
        df.loc[i,'Very High'] = df.loc[i,'Very High'] * conv_factor
    else:
        df.loc[i, 'WHP Total Acres'] = df.loc[i,'WHP Total Acres']
```

To iterate through 350K records, this is taking about 2 hours on my machine. I'm sure there has to be a more efficient way.

Comment: why not precompute `conv_factor` for all roles and then just use a `pd.where` clause to simply multiply those columns, I think you are making it more complicated then it has to be

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df['conv_factor'] = 1
df.loc[df['WHP Total Acres'] > df['GIS_ACRES'],'conv_factor'] = df['GIS_ACRES']/df['WHP Total Acres']

df['Very Low'] = df['conv_factor'] * df['Very Low']
.
.
.
```

Making a helper column for the `conv_factor` and then multiplying should get the result.

Simply using a `loc` to then change the required values.